# Using CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a project for my course. I have to make a 3 page responsive website but only allowed to use 1 CSS file for my styling. So my problem is how would i go about making each page look different.

Comment: Give each page a different class

Comment: So would this work for example? <body class=tutorial>

Comment: <body class="tutorial">, yes. I'd recommend reading up on the basics for example on w3schools web page.

Comment: It can be very simple. Please share your code. we will help you out.

Comment: Please change the title from the current one to something like" How to make 3 different resposive pages using single css file"

Answer (score 1):

You can use one CSS file to style multiple HTML pages. Most of the times it's good practice to re-use as much CSS as you can to avoid writing duplicate code. Just use different class names in  tags of different pages, and style them together in the same CSS file. Format can be as follows:

**file1.html** your first html file

```html
<head> 
  <link href="cssfile.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="class_file1">  
  <!-- body -->
</body>
```

**file2.html** Your second html file

```html
<head> 
  <link href="cssfile.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="class_file2">  
  <!-- body -->
</body>
```

**cssfile.css** (your css stylesheet)

```css
body
{
  /*common styling to prevent code duplication*/
}
.class_file1
{
  /*unique styling for the body of file1*/
}
.class_file2
{
  /*unique styling for the body of file2*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (in fact, it is a good practice to) include all of your CSS declarations on a single CSS file. Then, by assigning classes to your HTML tags you can easily make all 3 pages look different without using more than one CSS file, or resorting to inline (`style="color: red;"` for example).

On bigger projects, it is actually a good idea to split your CSS into separate, more focused files so you can easily manage them, but this is not the case here.

Take this snippet for example.

```css
/* Individual rules for each page */
.page1 {
  background: red;
}
.page2 {
  background: green;
}
.page3 {
  background: blue;
}

/* Rules shared by all 3 pages */
.pages {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="page1 pages">I'm page 1</div>
<div class="page2 pages">I'm page 2</div>
<div class="page3 pages">I'm page 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the responsive part of your CSS can be used on all 3 pages. To make the pages look different you can divide your CSS in sections with comments. Keep in mind that the 'C' in CSS stand for cascading which means, that you can (unintentionally) override values your already set. As Flink said, you could use classes like `.page-1` and `.page-2` to avoid that.

I would have a common part for all pages where I take care of the responsiveness.